# optimization Tic Tac Toe Game in C

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I'm beginner learner in C and one of the assignments I got was to write a Tic Tac Toe game. I have the game running but every time you place X on O position or vice versa it overwrites it. I would also appreciate comments on optimizing the code, because I'm a beginner and don't know a lot of concepts. Thank you! this is what I've got so far

```
#include<stdio.h>

void redrawBoard(char array[]);
void markBoard (int x, int o, char array[]);
int checkForWin(char array[]);

int checkForWin(char array[])
{   
int a;
char x = 'X';
char o = 'O';

 if (array[0] == x && array[4] == x && array[8] == x)  // winning cases for x 
    return 1;
 if (array[2] == x && array[4] == x && array[6] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[0] == x && array[1] == x && array[2] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[3] == x && array[4] == x && array[5] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[6] == x && array[7] == x && array[8] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[0] == x && array[3] == x && array[6] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[1] == x && array[4] == x && array[7] == x)
    return 1;
 if (array[2] == x && array[5] == x && array[8] == x)
    return 1;

 if (array[1] == x && array[4] == x && array[6] == x && array[8] ==x) //checking for draw with x combinations 1st pattern
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == x && array[2] == x && array[4] == x && array[7] ==x)
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == x && array[4] == x && array[5] == x && array[6] ==x)
    return 3;
 if (array[2] == x && array[3] == x && array[4] == x && array[8] ==x)
    return 3;

 if (array[1] == x && array[4] == x && array[5] == x && array[6] ==x) //checking for draw with x combinations 2nd pattern
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == x && array[4] == x && array[5] == x && array[7] ==x)
    return 3;
 if (array[2] == x && array[3] == x && array[4] == x && array[7] ==x)
    return 3;
 if (array[1] == x && array[3] == x && array[4] == x && array[8] ==x)
    return 3;



 if (array[0] == o && array[4] == o && array[8] == o) //// winning cases for o
    return 2;
 if (array[2] == o && array[4] == o && array[6] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[0] == o && array[1] == o && array[2] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[3] == o && array[4] == o && array[5] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[6] == o && array[7] == o && array[8] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[0] == o && array[3] == o && array[6] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[1] == o && array[4] == o && array[7] == o)
    return 2;
 if (array[2] == o && array[5] == o && array[8] == o)
    return 2; 

 if (array[1] == o && array[4] == o && array[6] == o && array[8] == o) //checking for draw with o combinations 1st pattern
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == o && array[2] == o && array[4] == o && array[7] == o)
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == o && array[4] == o && array[5] == o && array[6] == o)
    return 3;
 if (array[2] == o && array[3] == o && array[4] == o && array[8] == o)
    return 3;

 if (array[1] == o && array[4] == o && array[5] == o && array[6] == o) //checking for draw with o combinations 2nd pattern
    return 3;
 if (array[0] == o && array[4] == o && array[5] == o && array[7] == o)
    return 3;
 if (array[2] == o && array[3] == o && array[4] == o && array[7] == o)
    return 3;
 if (array[1] == o && array[3] == o && array[4] == o && array[8] == o)
    return 3;
 


 else
    return 0;

 return(a);
}

 void markBoard (int x, int o, char array[])
{
int i = 0;
char j = 'X';
char k = 'O';

while( x >= 1 && x <= 9) 
{
    array[x - 1] = j;
    redrawBoard(array);
    break;
}
while (o >= 1 && o <= 9)
{
    array[o - 1] = k;
    redrawBoard(array);
    break;
}

}

void redrawBoard(char array[])
{
printf(" Player 1 is X;       Player 2 is O;\n\n");
printf("              |      |        \n");
printf("           %c  |  %c   |  %c    \n",array[0],array[1],array[2]);
printf("        ______|______|______  \n");
printf("              |      |        \n");
printf("           %c  |  %c   |  %c    \n",array[3],array[4],array[5]);
printf("        ______|______|______  \n");
printf("              |      |        \n");
printf("           %c  |  %c   |  %c    \n",array[6],array[7],array[8]);
printf("              |      |        \n");
}

int main()
{
int x;
int o;
char array[9] = {'1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

printf("tic tac toe game\n");
redrawBoard(array);


while (checkForWin(array) == 0)
{
    printf("P1 start \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    markBoard(x,o,array);

    printf("P2 go on\n");
    scanf("%d", &o);
    markBoard(x,o,array);
}
if (checkForWin(array) == 1)
    printf("P1 won\n");
if (checkForWin(array) == 2)
    printf("P2 won\n");
if (checkForWin(array) == 3)
    printf("draw \n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is in urgent need of arrays and loops. You could define an array of triplets like `{ 0, 4, 8, 2, 4, 6, ... }` that define winning combinations, or you could derive that programmatically. Either way, you'd just spin over that loop looking for a match.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: You also want a function like `int playerHasWon(char player, char* board)` where that returns 0 for no win, or 1 for a winning condition. The key here is don't repeat code, re-use code.

Comment: Further tip: Don't call things with generic names like `array`. Call it `board`, as that's what it represents.

Comment: time spent learning to use a debugger is not time lost... it is time saved later.

Comment: There should only be a single `printf` in `void redrawBoard(char array[])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The problem you mentioned is that you do not have a test when you already have a value in this cell.
- About optimization:

1. Avoid a lot of `if cases`! Think about better check for checking who is winner.
   For example, look at this check:

   ```
    char winnerIs(char** Board, int i, int j) {
      if (Board[i][j] == Board[i][(j+1)%3]
       && Board[i][j] == Board[i][(j+2)%3])
      {
        // got a column
        return Board[i][j];
      }
      else if (Board[i][j] == Board[(i+1)%3][j] && Board[i][j] == Board[(i+2)%3][j])
      {
        // got a row
        return Board[i][j];
      }
      else if (i == j && Board[i][j] == Board[(i+1)%3][(j+1)%3]
                      && Board[i][j] == Board[(i+2)%3][(j+2)%3])
      {
        // got the forward diagonal
        return Board[i][j];
      }
      else if (i+j == 2 && Board[i][j] == Board[(i+2)%3][(j+1)%3]
                        && Board[i][j] == Board[(i+1)%3][(j+2)%3])
      {
        // got the reverse diagonal
        return Board[i][j];
      }
      else {
        // got nothing
        return 0;
      }
   ```
2. Avoid a lot of printing! Better use one structure for the game, for example a board - which is `char board[][]` or better `char** Board` if you want a dynamic game. And print the whole `board` once.
3. Instead of next code:

   ```
    printf("P1 start \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    markBoard(x,o,array);

    printf("P2 go on\n");
    scanf("%d", &o);
    markBoard(x,o,array);
   ```

Make something like this:

```
    int player = 1;
    char row, col; 
    player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;
    scanf("%c %c", &row, &col);
    markBoard(row, col, board);
```

Like that you don't need to duplicate a same code and it is automatic knows each turn, who's turn now.

4. Instead of next code:

   ```
    if (checkForWin(array) == 1)
        printf("P1 won\n");
    if (checkForWin(array) == 2)
        printf("P2 won\n");
    if (checkForWin(array) == 3)
        printf("draw \n");
   ```

Connect some conditions, like that:

```
    if (checkForWin(array) == 1 || checkForWin(array) == 2) {
        printf("Congratulations %c!\n", winner);
    } else {
        printf("Game ends in a draw.\n");
    }
```

5. To make more "beauty" code, you can added a structs which will manage the whole game, for example:

   ```
    typedef struct {
      int size;
      int **board; // the board
      /* scores of all options */
      int *rowScores;
      int *colScores;
      int topLeftBottomRightDiagonalScores;
      int topRightBottomLeftDiagonalScores;
    } Game;

    typedef struct { // position on the board
      int x;
      int y;
    } Position;
   ```
6. Your `void markBoard (int x, int o, char array[])` function makes to much iterations to print the whole board. Better create the whole board **once** and after that run on the whole board.

Comment: thank you, very helpful! will try to work on it and get better!